# OpenERP: group_by filter in many2one field doesn't applied

Tags: python, xml, odoo, many-to-one

on my object, I have a link to `'product.product'` as many2one field, in my object view, I registered `product_id` field:

```
class my_object(osv.osv):

    _columns = {

         'product_id': fields.many2one('product.product', 'Product'),

    }
```

`<field context="{'group_by':'categ_id','search_default_filter_to_sell':1}" name="product_id" />`

**(Please take a look at 'product.product' search view at addons/products/product_view.xml)**

when i select `"Search More ..."` option from dropdown, the tree view will just filtered by `'search_default_filter_to_sell'` and `group_by` filter is not activated, I tried all available `group_by` filters from `product.product` search view and no thing happen.

all objects with search-view that have group_by filter has this issue when you link them with many2one relation.

is this a bug? or i did something wrong?

I'm using Openerp v7.0, windows7, firefox21.

Answer (score 0):

You want default filter with two condition, in which one is group by 'categ_id' and second is 'to_sell':

First create filter for this condition :

```
        <record id="view_product_filter" model="ir.ui.view">
           '''''
           '''''
           <search>
                <field context="{'group_by':'categ_id'}" domain="[('to_sell','=',True))]" name="product_id" />
           </search>
           '''''''
        </record>
```

and after call default filter in "ir.actions.act_window":

```
         <field name="search_view_id" ref="view_product_filter"/>
         <field name="context">{'search_default_product_id':1}}</field>
```

It will help u...

Comment: Anup, thank u. but your answer has no relation with my Q at all. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't quite get your question, is `product_id` a simple many2one field or a many2one type relational field or a many2one type functional field? What "Search More ..." option did you select (a screenshot will be helpful)?
2. Also, this is how I define a filter in OpenERP 7.0:

   ```
   <filter string="Wenshan" icon="terp-personal"
           domain="[]" context="{'group_by': 'wenshan_id'}"/>
   ```